What is causing the spikes at the negative terminal of the opamp in response to the square wave?
I have a simple inverting amplifier as following in which the input is a square wave. By virtual short I expect node VF2 to be at 0V, but when I plot the voltage at VF2 I see spikes that are in sync with the squarewave transitions. I am observing similar behaviour in an actual circuit as well. What is causing this?



Is your square wave ideal?

The rising and falling edges cause the parasitic capacitances (e.g. junction capacitances of the input ESD protection diodes) of the op-amp to come into play because they are the high-frequency components of the incoming signal. Try to increase the rising and falling times and see the spike amplitudes decrease.

Does your real world implementation have bypass caps? 50 MHz op-amps are no toys that work without a proper design, such as bypass caps and proper PCB design. A breadboard is not a valid environment for this either.

@Justme yes, the PCB is designed with bypass caps and keeping signal integrity issues in mind.

@needbrainscratched Then you should post the actual schematics and actual PCB design to see if there is something wrong. Any stray capacitance at wrong place, even between resistor terminals, will be an issue at these frequencies. Also if input slew rate exceeds output slew rate, isn't the input overdriven? How fast input you have?

@Justme I cannot post the actual PCB because of proprietary restrictions, and a simulation doesn't model parasitic trace caps etc. I am observing the same behaviour in simulation so I am pretty sure it is an opamp property which is what I am trying to understand. The input is a 1KHz squarewave.

@needbrainscratched Yeah but we don't know if your simulation matches the real world. Simulation may have ideal square wave which a 50 MHz op-amp can never achieve inverting. Your real world can have too much output capacitance which makes the output unstable.

In your timing diagram the rounded corners of VF1 start before the generator edge starts. Can the OpAmp see the near future?

If you plot those graphs on a much smaller time scale, so that you can see that actual slewing of the op-amp output, you'll see that it does not transition between +1V and −1V instantaneously:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Note: The small output "peak" above +1V is caused by the rapid input transition being coupled capacitively (via parasitic capacitances inside the op-amp) to its output.
The descent of the op-amp's output (orange), from +1V down to −1V, is much slower than the input signal source (blue). The instantaneous change of \$V_{IN}\$, causes \$V_Q\$ (brown) to change too, but the op-amp's limited output slew rate means that it takes significant time for the output to "catch up", and restore the virtual ground.
If you slow down the input slew rate, to some value that that the op-amp can keep up with, then this spike will disappear. Here I've slowed the input transition just enough to almost make that happen:

As you can see, the virtual ground at Q is only slightly perturbed, until the output can settle at the expected value.

What is this intermediate state when virtual ground is disturbed? Does it mean feedback is broken? Like how does it work out from the math of opamp feedback?

@needbrainscratched It just means that op-amp imperfections give rise to a non-ideal virtual ground. Feedback isn't broken, but feedback can only happen as fast as the op-amp can change its output voltage. If you never ask the op-amp to work faster than it can, then this non-ideal "intermediate state" is mitigated, even eliminated.

@needbrainscratched the op-amp formula $V_{OUT}=A(V_+-V_-)$ is ideal behaviour, in reality the op-amp will have a time-dependent response, and that formula would contain a time $t$ term somewhere. However, we overlook that for convenience. Feedback will have the expected effect eventually, but not immediately, the real world is never so convenient.

What is your opinion on Antonio51's answer below....it's due to inherent nature of opamps response and not slew rate.

@needbrainscratched I agree that bandwidth is an imperfection which does contribute somewhat to non-ideal behavior, but I maintain that the issue you have here is 99% slew-rate, and 1% capacitive feed-through.

The small output peak as pointed in the note ... is probably due at the "delay" between input and output. It seems that it is a general problem pointed in the datasheet of the TL082 figures 24 and 26.


What is causing the spikes at the negative terminal of the opamp in response to the squarewave?

Logical.
The "real" opamp is, by definition, an "integrator" for "fast" input.
See the function Gain= Go*(1/(1+a*s)), with a= 0.01 for example.
So, to compute output correctly, it should "differentiate" the signal input ...
This can be demonstrated with mathematical background.
Uot is the opamp output (first plot), response to a step pulse, inverting.
epst is the negative input of the Opamp (second plot).

Note that the voltage of the pulse is quasi exactly the input divided by 2 ...
When global gain = -1 (1 V step input) ...
NB: the slew rate is not taken into account.
Here are two examples using different opamps.


One can see that the "pulse" amplitude at V- opamp input is quasi "identical".
The pulse "width" is dependent on the bandwidth/Slew rate of the opamp.
If the opamp has a greater bandwidth and higher SR, then the pulse should be shorter
(see LF13741 - 1 MHz - SR=0.5 V/us vs TL082c -4 MHz - SR=13 V/us).

So slew rate doesn't matter?

The "slew rate" can have a certain influence since it slows down the change in the output voltage. But as the calculation made with Maple (without the SR), the phenomenon depends on the "Go" and especially on the "a" (pole) of the OP amp (duration of the impulse). If the opamp has a greater bandwidth and higher SR, then the pulse should be shorter (see LF13741 - 1 MHz - SR=0.5 V/us  vs TL082c -4 MHz - SR=13 V/us).

If the pulse has a linear drop, then it is the slew rate that is important (LF13741). If the pulse has an exponential part (TL082c), then it is the pole placement that is important.

The spikes are caused by both the capacitance at that node, and the finite output slew-rate of the op amp.
There will be a voltage spike at the summing junction for the time it takes for the output to slew to the new step value of the square-wave,

I tried simulating with an opamp in which you can define the parameters, and I kept 0 junction cap and very high slew rate, but it still has this behaviour

@needbrainscratched what about gain-bandwidth (GBW)?
